# How to filler out iptable result base on certain fields and view it with tail command?

Tags: linux, iptables, logging, grep

I have this log :

```
Jan  26 01:05:47 server54 kernel: [41s58.6w4335] INPUT:DROP: IN=eth4 OUT= MAC=d3:ss:43:23:23:43 SRC=1.1.1.1 DST=127.0.0.0 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=254 ID=65259 PROTO=TCP SPT=53252 DPT=22 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
```

And I want to fitter out the results such that it only shows SRC and DST part with the time,showing at first, something like this:

```
 Jan  26 01:05:47 SRC=1.1.1.1 DST=127.0.0.0
```

I get as far as :

```
tail -f -n 2 /var/log/kern.log | grep 'INPUT'
```

But if I add second grep, It won't work! and I want to see live result so tail should be in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try if this works:

`sed -E 's/^([0-9a-zA-Z: ]*[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}).*(SRC=[0-9.:]+).*(DST=[0-9.:]+).*$/\1 \2 \3/g'`

It leaves me with `Jan  26 01:05:47 SRC=1.1.1.1 DST=127.0.0.0`

Regex explanation:
`^` beginning of line
`(` start capture group \1
`[0-9a-zA-Z: ]*` zero or more alphanum/colon/space
`[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}` date (nn:nn:nn)
`)` end capture group \1
`.*` all characters
`(` start capture group \2
`SRC=[0-9.:]+` SRC= followed by one or more numbers/colon/dot
`)` end of capture group \2
`.*` any character
`(` start capture group \3
`DST=[0-9.:]+` DST= followed by one or more numbers/colon/dot
`)` end of capture group \3
`.*` any character
`$` end of line

Then we just use `sed` with `-E` (extended regex) to replace each line in the file  with the three capture groups (\1 \2 \3)
There are probably way shorter regex to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct, but if you like to make it more fun, you could do this:

```
red=$(tput bold;tput setaf 1)
yellow=$(tput bold;tput setaf 3)
green=$(tput bold;tput setaf 2)
magenta=$(tput bold;tput setaf 5)
normal=$(tput sgr0)

tail -f -n 30 /var/log/kern.log | grep "DROP"|sed -E "s/^([0-9a-zA-Z: ]+)([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}).*(SRC=)([0-9.:]+).*$/$yellow\1$red \2$green \3$magenta\4/g"
```

It will colorize the output , and don't forget to use **double quotation** instead of **single quotation**.